# Rails: using associations in a find.all of index action

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a User.rb model and a Donation.rb model. User.rb `has_one :donation`, and Donation.rb `belongs_to :user`.

I created a form whereby a donation gets linked to a user. In the console, I'm able to do this

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :003 > user.donation.amount
 => 1
```

Similarily, I'm able to do this on the views/users/show.html.erb

```
<p>Donation:<%= @user.donation.amount if @user.donation.amount? %></p>
```

However, in `views/home/index.html.erb`, I'm doing this

```
<h3>Home</h3>
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <p>User: <%=link_to user.name, user %></p>
  <p>Email: <%= user.email if user.email %></p>
  <p>Name:<%= user.name %></p>
  <p>Donation:<%= user.donation.amount if user.donation.amount? %></p>
```

and getting this error

```
    NoMethodError in Home#index

Showing /Users/michaeljohnmitchell/Sites/leafpledge/app/views/home/index.html.erb where line #6 raised:

undefined method `amount?' for nil:NilClass
```

I'm assuming this is because the association between User.rb and Donation.rb doesn't work with the index action in the home_controller.rb because *every* user is being fetched rather than the particular user that I have in the `views/users/show.html.erb`.

```
 def index
    @users = User.all
  end
```

Any idea how I can get it to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `if` check should be checking if the donation exists, not if the amount exists:

```
<p>Donation:<%= user.donation.amount if user.donation %></p>
```

Or, you could use the `try` method which will avoid the undefined method error if `donation` is nil:

```
<p>Donation:<%= user.donation.try(:amount) %></p>
```